# Is there a way to customize the JAXB binding for the content (itemType) of an xs:list

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

Is there a way to customize the JAXB binding for xs:list? The folowing example:

```
<simpleType name="doubleList">
    <list itemType="double" />
</simpleType>
```

Will be bound by xjc to: `List<Double>`. However, I'd like to bind it to: `List<BigDecimal>`.

My initial setup was to define a binding like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings multiple="true" node="//xs:simpleType[@name='doubleList']/xs:list/@itemType">
     <jaxb:property>
          <jaxb:baseType name="java.math.BigDecimal" />
     </jaxb:property>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

However, this gives the following problem:

> XPath evaluation of "//xs:simpleType[@name='doubleList']/xs:list/@itemType" needs to result in an element.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to writing your own custom adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doubleList above was used elsewhere. Applying the binding on those spots, resulting in a correct Javaclass. Supprisingly, only choosing the proper base type was sufficient.

So place where the doubleList was used elsewhere:

```
   <complexType name="DirectPositionType">    
    <simpleContent>
        <extension base="gml:doubleList">
            <attributeGroup ref="gml:SRSReferenceGroup" />
        </extension>
    </simpleContent>
</complexType>
```

Binding

```
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/geometryBasic0d1d.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings multiple="true" node="//xs:complexType[@name='DirectPositionType']">
        <jaxb:property>
            <jaxb:baseType name="java.math.BigDecimal" />
        </jaxb:property>
    </jaxb:bindings>   
</jaxb:bindings>
```

resulting Java class:

```
public class DirectPositionType 
{
    @XmlValue
    protected List<BigDecimal> value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "srsName")
```